# Add main.js to Visualforce page

Tags: javascript, global-variables

Is there a way to include Salesforce's main.js file using an `<apex:includeScript />`?

On internal pages, the URL is something like this: `/jslibrary/1440733404000/sfdc/main.js`. I'm not sure where that number comes from, otherwise I'd be able to duplicate it. I need to do this manually because this is for a component; I don't know if the page that uses the component will include it. Any ideas? I could copy and manipulate the link for the SfdcCore.js, but that isn't as clean as I'd like.

Comment: That number represents some timestamp. This number `1440733404000` translates to `Fri Aug 28 2015 05:43:24 GMT+0200 (CEST)`. But if you want to use, then save the same file in static resource and then refer that in component / Vf page

Comment: I think it will be better if you download this JS and store it in a static resource.